# How to correctly find (and ultimately change) img src attribute using string value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<img id="unique.name.status" class="icon" src="OffStatus.png" alt="OFFLINE" />
```

At some point a client refreshes and I may need to change the image `src` and `alt` with id 'unique.name.status'. First, however, I must be able to find the specific image and, currently, I'm getting an `undefined` value with the following code:

```
statusimageId = "#" + user_id + ".status";
alert(statusimageId); // confirmed valid: '#unique.name.status'

statusimageSource = $(statusimageId).attr("src");   // returns 'undefined'
alert(statusimageSource);
```

NOTE: `user_id` is a value returned from JSON

Answer (score 6, accepted):

jQuery treats its selectors like CSS. Thus, if your `statusimageId` looks like `#USERID.status`, then jQuery is looking for the element with ID "USERID" and class "status". You'll want to use a different convention than `.` to add your "status" flag. Try:

`<img id="unique_name_status" class="icon" src="OffStatus.png" alt="OFFLINE" />`

and

`statusimageId = "#" + user_id + "_status";`

Comment: I was afraid of that. :) Thanks.

Comment: Added a field to my model that provides an `.underscoredname` property. Great explanation, btw.